# Условие с проверкой ключа в массиве

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив с такой структурой:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [name] => Name 1
        [value] => 10
        [field_name] => 421
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [name] => Name 4
        [value] => 10
        [field_name] => 421
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [name] => Name 6
        [value] => 10
        [field_name] => Name 4
    )
)
```

Как правильно проверить в массиве значения ключа `name`? Точнее, их наличие. В теории можно использовать `in_array`, но, что если такое же слово попадётся в других участках массива? Можно так же использовать `foreach`, но, вдруг кто-то знает более правильный способ проверки.

**Для лучшего понимания того, что нужно:** если в массиве ключ `name` содержит любое значение, кроме "Name 1", "Name 2" и "Name 3", то ...

Comment: `array_key_exists` - https://php.ru/manual/function.array-key-exists.html

Comment: И как мне поможет проверка наличия ключа?

Comment: Выбираем все значения по ключу `array_column($arr, 'name')`, а дальше проверяйте что угодно

Answer (score 0):

Смотря, что вы хотите после "то..." в последней вашей фразе.

Вообще, для упрощения есть несколько функций:

```
array_filter() - Фильтрует элементы массива с помощью callback-функции
array_map() — Применяет callback-функцию ко всем элементам указанных массивов
array_reduce() - Итеративно уменьшает массив к единственному значению, используя callback-функцию
array_walk() - Применяет заданную пользователем функцию к каждому элементу массива
```

Но под капотом они ничем не лучше и не хуже обычного `foreach`.

`foreach` же имеет более низкий уровень абстракции - явный перебор элементов массива, поэтому позволяет творить более изощренные манипуляции с массивом.

Вот так примерно:

```
$arr = array (
    0 => array (
        'name' => 'Name 1',
        'value' => 10,
        'field_name' => 421
    ),
    1 => array (
        'name' => 'Name 4',
        'value' => 10,
        'field_name' => 421
    ),
    2 => array (
        'name' => 'Name 6',
        'value' => 10,
        'field_name' => 'Name 4'
    )
);

$not_allow = array("Name 1", "Name 2", "Name 3"); // строки, которые ищем
```

вариант с `foreach`:

```
foreach($arr as $k=>$v){
    if( !in_array($v['name'], $not_allow)){
        // если содержит любое значение, кроме "Name 1", "Name 2" и "Name 3"  
    }else{
         // если содержит значение "Name 1" или "Name 2" или "Name 3"
    }
}
```

Если просто проверить на наличие и установить метку, то можно вообще "в одну строку":

```
$find = (preg_replace('/[\{\,]"name"\:"(('.implode(')|(', $not_allow).'))"/', '', json_encode($arr)) !== json_encode($arr)) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: А что не так с ответом? Интересно было бы услышать того, кто минуснул. Я бы вот так же сделал. Если есть способ более короткий и правильный, поделитесь. Плюсану

Comment: @Alexander Goroshev
Скорее всего или 1. не умеют читать между строк (у вас в вопросе акцент на ""поиск в ключе массива", а по сути нужен "поиск в значении элемента массива с ключом", или 2. кому-то не понравилось то, что foreach .более низкоуровневое и гибкое.

Comment: @Alexander Goroshev а короче может и можно, но это зависит от того "что вы хотите после "то..." )
Например, если нужно просто проверить наличие в массиве таких элементов, что 'name' не содержит  "Name 1", "Name 2" и "Name 3", то можно тупо сериализовать массив и регуляркой проверить. Если просто поменять что-то в том же элементе, в котором есть\нету искомое, то `array_map()`, `array_walk()`. А если что-то загадочное, то только `foreach`

Comment: По сути, нужно проверить каждый элемент массива, и если хоть в одном будет значение за пределами исключаемого списка, то будет что-нить типа `$test = '123';brake;`. То есть, изменится значение переменной.

Comment: Раз нужно менять перебираемый массив (его структуру, а не содержимое и/или структуру его элементов), тогда желательно `foreach`, чтобы не было неожиданностей и костылей.

Comment: Как раз массив не изменяется. Мне просто нужно объявить переменную, значение из которой потом в другом месте используется. То есть, если в массиве найдётся любое значение, кроме исключенных, ставим 1, а если не найдёт - то 2. И всё. Сам массив при этом не затрагивается

Comment: Ну метку выставлять тоже лучше при явном переборе. Всякие коллбэки - это извраты с областью видимости переменой. Коллбеки хороши только,если манипуляции в пределах итерации происходят.

Comment: Чувствую, старый добрый `foreach` ничем не заменить) В любом случае, спасибо. Если никто ничего не добавит, можно будет закрыть вопрос

Comment: немного дополнил ответ